# Error in mongodb: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE

Tags: java, mongodb, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I am using maven to manage the jar, and my dependencies about mongodb are below:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-mongodb -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

But when I starting the springmvc program, there is an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultMongoTypeMapper.<init>(DefaultMongoTypeMapper.java:65)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.<init>(MappingMongoConverter.java:108)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.AbstractMongoConfiguration.mappingMongoConverter(AbstractMongoConfiguration.java:192)
at com.aixueniao.server.configuration.MongoConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ee562bf3.CGLIB$mappingMongoConverter$5(<generated>)
at com.aixueniao.server.configuration.MongoConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ee562bf3$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$973f1472.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
at com.aixueniao.server.configuration.MongoConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ee562bf3.mappingMongoConverter(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
... 85 more
```

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with it? Maybe there are errors with the versions of the dependencies, but how can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it looks like jar conflict, maybe you can clean and degrade the version and check.

Comment: Get rid of mongo java driver dependency. The spring mongo db dependency has a transitive dependency on mongo java driver. The current spring mongo release version can only support 2.x mongo driver version. If you need 3.x mongo driver support, you'll need to use the one of the spring  mongo release candidate version.

Comment: Its a library version conflict error. degrade your spring-data-mongodb to 1.7.2.RELEASE.it 'll work out. otherwise try to apply exclusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a multiple library version conflict error.simple way is degrade your spring-data-mongodb version 1.9.5.RELEASE to 1.7.2.RELEASE

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
```

otherwise try to find conflict library and apply exclusion in  spring-data-mongodb dependancy